# exporting the dependencies of a Visual Studio solution

Tags: build-process

I have a big project I am working on right now using Visual Studio 2008.
The solutions is composed by several project in Visual C# and Visual C++.

Clicking on a project node , and selecting from the manu the item "Project Dependencies" I can find the list of dependencies I want to export.

Do you know a way to export this list on a file someway?

Thanks
EO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are already stored in the Visual Studio Solution and Project files.
Look for the `<ProjectReference>` tag.

With some post-processing, you could copy them from there and write them to another file.

You can also use the EnvDTE.BuildDependency class to retrieve the dependencies programmatically.

Comment: Can you explain how they are in the solution file? I am looking at my solution file which contains 3 executables and 10 libraries. 1 exe requires 7 of the 10 libraries, another exe requires 7 of the 10, but 2 different ones than the first, and the last exe requires 5 of the 10..

so How do I get a list of which dlls go with which exe?

Comment: @Dss Check the Project files for the <ProjectReference> tag. (I've edited my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Project Dependency as opposed to Project Reference, the former just imposes a build ordering, they are stored in the solution file. Look for lines like

```
ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
```